# Github rendering Asciidoc callouts: icons are missing

Tags: github, asciidoc

Is it possible to make GitHub render an Asciidoc `[source]` with callout icons as shown in [AsciiDoc Syntax Quick Reference, Source Code](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#source-code)

```
----
line of code  // <1>
line of code  # <2>
line of code  ;; <3>
line of code  <!--4-->
----
<1> A callout behind a line comment for C-style languages.
<2> A callout behind a line comment for Ruby, Python, Perl, etc.
<3> A callout behind a line comment for Clojure.
<4> A callout behind a line comment for XML or SGML languages like HTML.
```

[image]

> Here is what I got with GitHub

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To enable image-based icons, you set the icons attribute in the document header to the value font (see https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/icons-font/)

```
= My Document
:icons: font
```

Comment: Nope. The question is specifically about rendering in the GitHub UI. To my knowledge GitHub UI does not honor the `:icons: font` setting.